# NSData not returning bytes

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5, nsdata

Ok I have a password stored in the keychain and I am attempting to update the password in the keychain and on my server. When the user types in the new password in an UIAlertView the password is updated in the keychain and so on. The problem I am having is when you cancel or try to do it again the value retrieve from the keychain is retuned as the the string instead of in bytes.

I set the new password in the keychain like this using the keychain wrapper

```
[keychainItem setObject:newPassword forKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];
```

the first time i go through the process it works fine but if I attempt to change it again and go through the process i get

```
-[__NSCFString bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

it crashes in this method when
     NSString *keychainPassword = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:pass encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
is called. in the NSLog call it is retuning the string of the password and not the bytes, any reason why?

```
-(BOOL)checkIfOldPasswordMatches {
NSLog(@"checkIfPasswordMatches");

 //gets password from keychain
NSData *pass = [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];
if (pass == nil || [pass length] == 0) {
    [UIAlertView error:@"Username and Password does not exist. You must create a login."];
}

 //shows output of password which should return bytes
NSLog(@"pass %@", pass);
NSString *keychainPassword = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:pass encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"keychain %@", keychainPassword);
if ([oldPassword isEqualToString:keychainPassword]) {
    NSLog(@"yes");
    return YES;
} else
    NSLog(@"no");
return NO;

}
```

Comment: There is no method on NSString named `bytes`.

Comment: (And where, exactly, is the error occurring??)

Comment: (Your problem is that `pass` is an NSString, not NSData.)

Comment: Yes that is the problem. I am confused why the first time through the password is retuned as NSData but when I go through it again with the new password is returned as NSString.

Comment: Probably because you changed it somewhere in-between.

Comment: Ok then when I retrieve the new password from the UIAlertView do I need to convert it to NSData then send it to the keychain? I thought [keychainItem setObject:newPassword forKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)]; did that?

Comment: Where in the documentation does it say that it changes the object type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`kSecValueData`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000898-CH4g-SW132) specifies that the item is some data, not a reference to another item (kSecValueReference) or a persistent reference (kSecValuePersistentRef).  It doesn't mean that the item value is stored/returned as an `NSData` instance.

The type of object you put in is the type of object you will get out, so if you put in an NSString you will get back an NSString.

You need to change your code to either *always* use an `NSData` instance or *always* use an `NSString`, converting as required.